# C++ bad_cast exception casting *this to derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, dynamic-cast

I am attempting a virtual template function implementation. I have it working when casting `this` pointer to a pointer to subclass template, but I cannot get it to work when I cast `*this` to reference to subclass, why?

```
template <typename T> struct BB; // forward reference (not bound until instantiation in main)
struct AA
{
    virtual ~AA(){}
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T && t)
    {
        dynamic_cast<BB<T>*>(this)->operator()(std::forward<T>(t)); // works!
        dynamic_cast<BB<T>&>(*this)(std::forward<T>(t));            // compiles but throws bad_cast
    }
};
template <typename T>
struct BB : AA
{
    void operator()(T t) { std::cout << "BB::operator()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    BB<int> bb;
    int k = 5;
    static_cast<AA&>(bb)(k);
}
```

Comment: What does "works" mean?

Comment: Please also try `static_cast<AA&>(bb)(5);` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB, calls `void BB::operator()(T & t)`

Comment: So young, so innocent, so easily mislead...

Comment: @KerrekSB, fixed receiving method signature.

Comment: Ah, yes, if you wanted the rvalue version to work (because then `T = int`). If you want to keep your lvalue reference version, though, then just use lvalue references everywhere and it'll be easy and clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your call `static_cast<AA&>(bb)(k);`, `T` is deduced as `int &`, and the most-derived object containing `*this` is not of type `BB<int &>`. So both casts fail, and your pointer indirection produces undefined behaviour.

Comment: Worth to mention that "undefined behaviour" in this case *seems* to do the right thing. As OP is calling a function which is not accessing its own object, the function prints the expected result even though `this == nullptr` (which was returned by the dynamic cast for the pointer).

Comment: This is quite interesting. Is this fix working as intended by the OP? http://ideone.com/5Cahf7

Comment: @DanielJour, while we're at it, might as well `remove_cv` as well.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod In that case use `std::decay`.

Comment: @DanielFrey: The best kind of undefined behaviour (in the sense of bringing you a million dollar lawsuit when your self driving orbiter has crashed into an orphanarium) is the kind that "seems to do the right thing" ;-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yep. Lesson for OP: When using `dynamic_cast` with pointers, always check for `nullptr` unless you are *really* *really* sure what you are doing or you are *really really* rich and can affort that lawsuit :)